# Converting Dependency tree into sequence of Arc-eager transitions

Tags: nlp, syntaxnet, dependency-parsing

Currently I'm trying to build syntax-aware NMT model.
In this project, I need the sequence of one of three transition actions (SHIFT, REDUCE-L, REDUCE-R)

Similar to what is in the image 
[a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Ian.png)

This chunk represents the transition-based dependency for 2 sentences(1 for 1 chunk split by empty lines)

I'm using `Syntaxnet` to get the dependency parse tree first, but it doesn't directly provide that transition action sequences. 
It's results are as follows,

[b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t5IZ.png)

Is it possible to get the action sequences similar to this image? Is it possible to convert what is achieved from this image to the original image's format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function that converts a dependency tree to a sequence of transitions is called an oracle. It is a necessary component of a statistical parser.
The transitions you described (shift, reduce-l, reduce-r)¹ are those of the *arc-standard* transition system (not the *arc-eager* system, which is: shift, left-arc, right-arc, reduce).

Pseudo-code for an arc-standard oracle:

```
stack = [] # stack[0] is the top of the stack
buffer = [w1, w2, ..., wn]

while len(buffer) > 0 or len(stack) != 1:
    if stack[0] is the head of stack[1]:
        apply left-arc
    if stack[1] is the head of stack[0]:
        if there is a token in the buffer whose head is stack[0] 
            # (i.e not all children of stack[1] have been attached to it)
            apply shift
        else:
            apply right-arc
```

These [slides](http://demo.clab.cs.cmu.edu/fa2015-11711/images/b/b1/TbparsingSmallCorrection.pdf) present the two parsing algorithms and their oracles.

¹Reduce-left, reduce-right are often named right-arc and left-arc in the context of dependency parsing.